# Cannot get Ajax data on init in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am sure the problem is about asynchronization but I could not find the solution. I have created a service which gets an array of JSON data. In my component, I would like to show this data when the page is loaded. 
I don't get any data when the page is loaded, but I created a button and put the same function on its onclick event. I get the data on on click event. What am I doing wrong?

my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PostService} from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `

  {{test}}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of jsonArray">
    {{item.title}} a
    </li>

  </ul>
  <button on-click="onClick()">button</button>
  `


})
export class AppComponent {
  test;
  jsonArray : any[];
  constructor(private _postService : PostService){


  }

  onClick(){
    this.jsonArray = this._postService.getPosts();
    this.test = "clicked";
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.jsonArray = this._postService.getPosts();
     this.test = "init";

   }

}
```

and my service class

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class PostService {

    private _url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    jsonArray: any[];
    getPosts():any[]{
        //return this._http.get(this._url).map(res =>res.json());
         this._http.get(this._url).subscribe(response => {
           this.jsonArray = response.json();
           console.log(response.json());
           console.log("jsonArray",this.jsonArray);
        });

        return this.jsonArray;
    }

    createPost(post){
        return this._http.post(this._url,JSON.stringify(post)).map(res =>res.json());
    }
    constructor(private _http:Http ){

    }




}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error. I am geeting result using your code. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: no errors, i am trying to see the data on the page not on console. Are you seeing the data on the page ? @RajBahadurSingh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your service:

1. Your `return` is outside the callback, so the initial empty array will be returned
2. Even if it wasn't outside, you **cannot** return data from `subscribe`.

I suggest you read up on asynchronicity: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Also this [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2) explains this behavior in more Angular scenario.

Also read up on on the **[official tuto of http](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)**.

That being said, very shortly said - you need to `map` in service and `subscribe` in component.

As to your question:

> I don't get any data when the page is loaded, but I created a button and put the same function on its onclick event. I get the data on on click event.

So let's dive in your service method and see what is going on:

```ts
getPosts():any[]{
     this._http.get(this._url).subscribe(response => {
       // hey, I'm doing this request now, but I don't know how long it will take
       this.jsonArray = response.json();
       console.log(response.json());
       console.log("jsonArray",this.jsonArray);
    });
    /* okay, so I fired the above request, I won't wait until it is complete, 
       I'll just execute the below while I am waiting!*/
    return this.jsonArray;
}
```

So, when you fire the request on `OnInit` it performs the http-request, and while it is executing it returns `this.jsonArray` before the http request has finished executing.

So now when you click the button, it refires the http-requests and before it has finished completing it again returns you `this.jsonArray` before that. But hey, now we actually have values there from the **previous** request, so that is why you get the data just fine!

As earlier mentioned, you cannot return data from subscribe anyway, even if it was inside callback like so:

```ts
getPosts():any[]{
     return this._http.get(this._url).subscribe(response => {
        ....
        return this.jsonArray; // WON'T WORK!
    });
}
```

So what you can do, is return data from `map`, so do:

**Service:**

```ts
getPosts():any[]{
     this._http.get(this._url)
       .map(res => res.json())
    });
}
```

**Component:**

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  this._postService.getPosts()
    .subscribe(data => this.jsonArray = data)
}
```

I **really** recommend to read the provided links carefully and with thought :)

Comment: You are very welcome, glad I could clarify things a bit for you! :)